# Rails Error Message Displays Locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, braintree-rails

When submitting a form locally that also creates a Braintree Transaction, I am able to display any Braintree processing errors. The Braintree Instance Variables is stored in @result.

**Error Messages Displaying Properly Locally**

[Error Messages Rendering Properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGRKo.png)

This is the **_error_messages** partial

```
<% if @result.try(:errors) %>
<%# if @result.errors.present? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@result.errors.count, "error")     %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @result.errors.each do |error| %>
      <li><%= error.code %> <%= error.message %></li> <br>
    <% end #do %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I use the **@result.try(:errors)** since @result doesn't get initialized until later in the controller action.

The same code on Heroku renders the error message partial box (font and formatting) but not any of the errors:

**Error Messages Not Displaying Properly on Heroku**

[Error Messages Not Rendering Properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPI9s.png)

I've confirmed in the Heroku logs that the Braintree result did return an error.  I don't think it's a Braintree problem and the code works fine locally.  Other forms being submitted with errors will render error messages properly on Heroku.

Any ideas?

Thanks

David

Comment: My first thought would be CSS or Javascript files are have an incorrect path when deployed to Heroku.  Use a content delivery network for common CSS & JavaScript and check the paths of any CSS or JavaScript files you added to your project (i.e. files that are in your Git repository)

Comment: I precompiled the assets before deploying to Heroku.  The CSS is also rendering properly, just not displaying the correct content.

Comment: This problem resolved itself. Not sure what the root cause was.